# Data Processing: Excel vs Desmos Discrepancy

Tags: data-analysis

I have the following set of data:

[image]

Plotting this on Excel gave me a nice, smooth curve:

[image]

With the Polynomial Regression function, I get a 5th order polynomial that fits very well:

[image]

The issue arises when I transfer both the data values and the best fit curve to Desmos. The two don't seem to have any correlation at all!

[image]

I've checked the equations and the data innumerable times, and there doesn't seem to be any typos. Any ideas for why this discrepancy arises? I've done the regression, the data plotting, and the typo-check numerous times (even on multiple laptops), but have had no luck so far.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably due to the precision of the coefficients.You are throwing some big numbers  around in that polynomial to get a small value out.

Comment: As confirmed with @ClaudeLeibovici's answer, the precision of the coefficients it was. Amazing how you spotted it - Thank you.

Comment: I think the underlying issue is that a 5th-order polynomial is overfitting. You probably get more sensible numbers with a fourth-order fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to try with exact values of the coefficients for the model $$y=\sum_{i=0}^5 a_i x^i$$
$$a_0=-\frac{1367716921770523}{33264123750}$$ $$a_1=\frac{318769904368}{12096045}$$ $$a_2=-\frac{898557942649}{133056495}$$ $$a_3=\frac{115064631832}{133056495}$$ $$a_4=-\frac{490812512}{8870433}$$ $$a_5=\frac{3423040}{2419209}$$

As Joffan commented, the problem is more than likely due to the precision of the coefficients generated by Excel.

**Edit**

Concerning the problem of the overfit (as commented by Joffan), let us have a look at the sum of squares of residuals $S_n$ as a function of $n$, the degree of the polynomial. We have 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & S_n \\
 1 & 0.176991 \\
 2 & 0.050324 \\
 3 & 0.017965 \\
 4 & 0.003115 \\
 5 & 0.002169 \\
 6 & 0.000903 \\
7  & 0.000707 \\
8 &  0.000661
\end{array}
\right)$$

As you can see, for $n > 4$, the improvement is just very marginal. If I may suggest, plot $S_n$ as a function of $n$ and this will become quite clear.

Comment: Thank you so much. If I could, I'd post an image of this new curve going perfectly through all of the data values, but I unfortunately cannot. I do not understand how you were able to compute the exact values, though; could you please explain it to me?

Comment: Well ! I wrote $7.45=\frac{745}{100}$, $-0.739=-\frac{739}{1000}$ and so on; then I minimized the sum of the squared errors using exact arithmetic (through the normal equations).

Comment: I did it on excel, but got the answers rounded to a number of decimal places. How can I get exact fractions? Also, it took me a lot of time to get the rounded manually as I had to make a 6x6 matrix and do some matrix multiplication. Is that how you did it?

Comment: Please respond - I did it on excel, but got the answers rounded to a number of decimal places. How can I get exact fractions? Also, it took me a lot of time to get the rounded manually as I had to make a 6x6 matrix and do some matrix multiplication. Is that how you did it?

Comment: As I said earlier, I converted the values to fractions in order to be able to use exact arithmetic. Then, I used the so-called normal equations in order to compute all the required sum and finally solved the $6\times 6$ matrix problem to get the coefficients.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what software did you use?

Comment: No problem ! I have a very old version of Maxima which I modified over many years for some specific needs of mine. You can download it for free from SourceForge http://maxima.sourceforge.net/download.html

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici How were you able to get an entire table of the Sum of Square of Residuals values? Did you have to compute the solutions to the $3x3, 4x4, 5x5...$ matrix to do so? If not, how did you do it?

Comment: @GoodChessPlayer. This is what I had to do. But f you think abour it, it is very small work (almost when using matrix calculations). Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I have similar data as what OP has posted, and I'm also trying to find exact coefficients. Your answer begins with a simple equation - is that all you used to compute the exact coefficients? I am using Excel, and the way I'm doing it is very tedious (I have to compute the sum of all x, x^2, x^3... from the data, create a matrix, inverse the matrix, and then multiply it with another matrix). And I have to repeat this process for every different ordered polynomial, before I can compute the SSR values. So, the way I am doing it is not easy work - Is that how you did it as well?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am amazed by how you were able to do all that in just an hour after OP posted the question. Please do tell me a way I can make my method less tedious, if you know/used a different approach.

Comment: @GoodChessPlayer. As I said, I use exact arithmetics to obtain the exact coefficients; I do not suppose that you could do this with Excel. For the SSR, you do not need so much accuracy. In fact, I was cheating a little since I have a sofware of mine doing all the work automatically given the degree of the polynomial (the result is also the exact SSR).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I understand. I want to thank you for your time.

Comment: @GoodChessPlayer. You are very welcome ! Do not hesitate to contact me if I can be of any help (my e-mail address is in my profile).